# Same output for all the OpenCV4Android Samples

Tags: java, opencv, android

I have installed OpenCV4Android sample files and starting executing it. It's been a tough case for me as I see a bit of same output for all the samples which I run on my Emulator.

I know that These are not the correct outputs. What would be the reason for this?

Am running on API 22 and on Android Version 5.1.1

Screenshots of my ouputs

[Camera Preview Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trhQn.png)

[Color Blob Detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mhE4.png)

Please let me know the reason for getting this same Outputs

Thanks

Comment: I guess it's my camera problem in the Emulator. If I start a camera in the normal mode it's displaying the same boxes as above. I tried by modifying the settings in the Emulator but still the day wasn't mine.